# Revealing host name of client accessing Postgres

Tags: postgresql, client, hostname

I have a request to reveal the hostname of clients that accessing the database. The main purpose is to pinpoint who accesses the DB and when. Is it possible?

This query here does not cut it :

```
   select pid as process_id, 
       usename as username, 
       datname as database_name, 
       client_addr as client_address, 
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity;
```

Update
I check the rDNS using `dig -x ipadd`. it works. Look at the result below
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to set [`log_hostname`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-HOSTNAME) to `on`. Then you will get the client host name in the column `client_hostname` of `pg_stat_activity`.

Note that that only applies to connections established *after* you change `log_hostname`, since the host name is looked up when the client connects.

Comment: it does not work. `client_hostname` is still empty. i have reloaded the config and restarted the pg service. what seems to be the problem ? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I have no idea what you did wrong. Perhaps reverse DNS doesn't work at your site.

Comment: i check rDNS using `dig`. it works. see the picture on the original question. But, maybe I have to set the rDNS somewhere else... @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: No, it is DNS on the database server machine. Perhaps you were looking at connections established before you changed the parameter.

Comment: "Note that only applies to connections established after you change `log_hostname`, since the host name is looked up when the client connects." 
yes, I changed the parameter then I make a new connection. still the `client_hostname` shows NULL. What else should I check ? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Sorry, PostgreSQL just doesn't behave the way you describe. You must have made some basic error, like change the wrong configuration file.